# Is it possible to draw a closed grid without any spur?

Tags: qt, qwt

As you can see,the grid of QWT has many spurs by default,and below grid is closed by a frame which is added manually by myself in ppt. Question is:

Is it possible to draw a closed grid in QWT?

[image: demo image]

Comment: Please clarify the question and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it.

Comment: what is your meaning about `QWT`? [this](https://github.com/opencor/qwt) or qtwidget? why you didn't use qtcharts? see [OpenGL Accelerated Series Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-openglseries-example.html)

Comment: @Parisa.H.R QWT is https://github.com/opencor/qwt

Comment: @Parisa.H.R this is not for specific case,for every grid will looks this by default

Comment: Well, to answer your question, I have to check and test the source.
It takes time, but I suggest you try the Qt chart as well

Comment: Are you just wanting a border around your chart?

Comment: @JarMan,I updated the image,and it should be more descriptiive now,and I want grid close like 口， no colums or rows got protruded like 井

Comment: @Parisa.H.R,you may have not used QWT at all based on your replies.This problem isn't specific,no source code need,because every QWT example has this problem.